# Agent Xps getting disabled automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

In one of SQL Server 2012 server, agent Xps is getting disabled automatically. There is no set pattern for the same and the issue started all of a sudden. Through profiler it was found that application named `SQL AGent- Enable\disable Agent Xps` is disabling the XPs. And the later is enabled by SQL Agent-Initial BootProbe.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem that I just resolved. Turned out, a new group policy had been applied to our server. This group policy disallowed domain users access to the D:, E:, & F: drives. Our SQL Server Agent was configured to write out its error log to the E: drive. As the Log On account for the SQL Server Agent service was a domain based account, SQL Server Agent was now unable to write to its log file. It died immediately at service start up. It was very frustrating in that we saw nothing in the Windows Event Viewer other than that the service started up and then stopped.

Answer (score 1):

To enable Agent of the SQL Server, run following.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: It is getting disabled, after enabling.

Comment: You might check to see if a Policy has been enabled that has this impact on your SQL Server Agent.

Comment: This may seem out of left field but is there any chance that there is an agent job that disables it?